# What is the significance of the bamboo tree that naruto carries at the end of the op?

Tags: naruto

Naruto carries a bamboo tree at the end with some stuff hanging from it like a Christmas tree.
Is there any significance to the bamboo?

[image: naruto]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to me to be a reference to Tanabata festival.

Tanabata is a traditional star festival, celebrating the meeting of the deities Orihime and Hikoboshi (represented by the stars Vega and ALtair).

According to legend,

> the Milky Way separates these lovers, and they are allowed to meet only once a year on the seventh day of the seventh lunar month of the lunisolar calendar. [(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanabata)

There is a tradition to write wishes on small pieces of paper and hang them on a bamboo tree:

[image]

So I would way Naruto is holding a small wishing tree with wishes from his friends.